# Shell script to run gradle project

Tags: java, bash, shell, gradle, makefile

I'm a complete beginner with writing shell scripts, and with using gradle for that matter.

I have a gradle project whose output is some images. I pass two paths as command line arguments that represents a directory of .java sources, and an output file name:

`gradle run --args='C:/user/.../src/ result'`

My project parses the sources and generates class diagrams of each file, then outputs an image showing all of the UML class diagrams for each source file.

My "client" expects the following from the command line:
`commandName <.java source> <output file name>`

Where the ".java sources" is the source directory containing .java files, and the "output file name" is the name of the image containing class diagrams.

I would like to create a shell script, or enact some method to create a neat command like above, and also make sure that this script can run the gradle project with given arguments.

I would also like to ensure that anyone can download my gradle project, and be able to run this command with minimal setup. Would I be better off using a makefile here?

Edit: 
The shell script is more minimal than I thought. Here is all I have so far:

```
gradle run --args="$*"
```

I've read that I can use an alias to execute this with a "simple" name. If someone else downloads my project, how can they run this script with the simple name without setting the alias themselves?

Comment: What's not working? What's the problem?

Comment: I can run my shell script using the command ./myscript.sh arg1 arg2, which works fine, but I would like to make it so that the command appears without "./" like, myscript arg1 arg2

Comment: You’ll have to add the directory that contains the shell script to the `PATH` environment variable then – or move/copy/symlink the script to a directory that already _is_ on the `PATH`.